# Spring Batch and Hibernate - Mass emailing application

Tags: spring, hibernate, email, batch-processing, spring-batch

We're developing a spring batched and Hibernate based application which will be responsible for sending out 1000s of emails.

In short, currently there is one job defined with a single step.

```
<job id="emailJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" restartable="true"
     job-repository="jobRepository">
    <step id="emailJobFetchUsers">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk reader="emailItemReader" processor="emailItemProcessor" writer="emailItemWriter" commit-interval="1"/>
        </tasklet>
        <end on="COMPLETED"/>
        <fail on="FAILED"/>
    </step>
    <listeners>
        <listener ref="loggingListener"/>
    </listeners>
</job>
```

- emailItemReader extends HibernateCursorItemReader and will return the row's entity (in this case a record which represents the customer's choice of email)
- emailItemProcessor generates and send the customer specific email
- emailItemWriter simply updates the entity which some information such as a last sent date

Whilst this works the I am not sure if it should all be one step or if there should be one step responsible each action. My main concern is regarding restartability and recovery.  That is, such an exception occur for one user (maybe due to an invalid email address or a problem generating the email) or if the application server went down and was restarted I want it to be able to pick up sending emails from where it left off.

Can anyone advise on the above?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be restartable. Check the javadoc of your reader's superclass. You need to be careful with the following, though:

- you need to maintain order in your query -- the reader will just start from the item it failed on, so each query execution must return items in the same order
- it might be tricky if the entity modification in itemWriter affects the query result -- e.q. if you filter by last sent date, then it will not work as expected

What's more I believe that if the following happens:

1. a job execution fails
2. a new customer is inserted to the DB\
3. the job restarts

Then the query result might be also different than during the first (failed) execution. If such scenario is possible in your app, then I suggest to add some conditions to prevent it -- like adding a check to the query to skip customers registered after first job-execution time.